# How can I change the value stored in a variable after click command in python (library import click)

Tags: python

I am beginner, so I tried solving this problem and I couldn't.I don't know how to explain the problem but I'll try, First you'll have to create 2 python files 1 called setup.py and the other one game.py. Most people will think this is weird but I want you to see what happens when you run the code so you'll understand more.

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name ="Game",
    version= "0.1",
    py_modules=['Game'],
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points = '''
        [console_scripts]
        Game=Game:cli
    ''',
)
```

game.py

```
from random import *
from time import *
import click
dt = 5000
userinventroy = ["Phone"]
f = open("wallet.txt","w")
f.write(str(dt))
f.close

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
def bet():
    global dt
    global f
    guessthenumber = randint(1,2)
    if int(input("Guess the number:")) == guessthenumber:
        print("Correct you won 250 DT!!")
        w = 250
        f = open("wallet.txt","r")
        old_wallet = f.read()
        int(old_wallet)
        new_wallet = old_wallet + w
        f = open("wallet.txt","w")
        f.write(str(new_wallet))
        f.close()
    else:
        print("You lost.")

@cli.command()
def wallet():
    global f
    f= open("wallet.txt","r")
    print("You have :",f.read())
    f.close()
```

After you have these two files created I want you to go to the terminal and type
" pip install --editable . " (without strings).

The main problem now is : so once you start this betting game which is guessing a number from 1 to 5 and if you guess it you get 250 coins or credits but it doesn't store it

if you type game wallet to check the new value it is the same value that i set and this is killing me, Please i would truly appreciate it if you help me, thank you.

Comment: Are you saying when you re-run the script it isn't stored? Or are you saying the wallet variable isn't being assigned to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe make a file and store the wallet count in there:

```
f = open('wallet.txt', 'w' )
f.write(str(wallet))
f.close()
```

Then when they play the game again:

```
f = open("wallet.txt", "r")
print("Wallet balance: ",f.read())
f.close()
```

EDIT: If you have multiple users, and want to track their balances - ask them to enter a username then use that username as the file name:

```
user = input("Enter your name")
filename = user + " .txt"

f = open(filename, "w")
f.write(str(wallet))
f.close()
```

Now you'll have files for each user, and can also read their file when they put in their username.

EDIT 2: If you are wanting to carry on adding to it do this:

First we want to scrape what's in the user's wallet already, then replace it:

```
print("You won 250!") #or whatever they won

#reading wallet file
f = open('wallet.txt', 'r')
old_wallet = f.read()
new_wallet = old_wallet + wallet

#writing to wallet file
f = open('wallet.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(new_wallet)) #making sure it's a float what's in the file
f.close()
```

Final edit: adding to the wallet at the start causes errors as it has already been written to.

Comment: f = open("Wallet.txt","r") what is r and can you explain to me more, i'm quite new.
My guess is that "r" stands for read and "w" stands for write, im i correct ?

Comment: yes you are correct, you can learn more about python files [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp). Also if this has solved your question, please accept it. Thanks ;)

Comment: I managed to get it working but the problem is if the user won 250 and i add it to the file it will print 5000250 and it won't count them, do you have a solution please.

Comment: @BackpainYT check my edited answer mate, if you have any problems with it let me know

Comment: f.write only accepts strings i tried using integers and floats but it gives an error everytime

Comment: oh okay, sorry i'm a bit rusty with file writing. check the code again, i just took it out, it should work now.

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str check my edited question

Comment: no don't add anything to it, just make it f.write(new_wallet)

Comment: i rewrote your code for you, that is working for me. I also added something to check if the wallet.txt exists, you can take this out if you want as I am only just now noticing you have already created the file at the start of the code.

Comment: I was a little stupid there, everytime its reseting the value to 5000, shame on me, Also i did manage to make it work, just wanted to say that there is no way your code works because (f.write) only takes strings and you have to convert it to string so its f.write(str(newwallet)).

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear with what i exactly did. If your question is solved either accept my answer, or post what you did to make it work and accept that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem man if it wasn't you i wouldn't solve the problem, thanks for helping me out. I did post the answer if you want to check it out but its not an efficient fix it needs more thinking but it works for now.

Comment: We got there in the end lol. I edited my answer to help others what come across this question. I think your answer is a bit confusing without mine so i would accept mine to help others.

Comment: Your answer still doesn't work, as i've told you the write function only applies to strings, if you type it like that it would show a type error.

Comment: I will mark yours now :), can you upvote my question so i can do more stuff on the forums.

Comment: done. have a good day man, glad i could help. and you helped me remember how to write files all over again ;)

Comment: No problem man, how can i add you as a friend in this site because i am quite new in programming and you may help me in the future if you don't mind :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227559/discussion-between-insula-and-backpainyt).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was i did set a variable called "dt = 5000" which is the user wallet at the beginning of the code and everytime you win the bet, 250 won't be added since its getting reset everytime you type a command, what i did was i set the variable in the function this solved the main problem now but it will lead to more problems, this is a fix but not an efficient one.

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name ="Game",
    version= "0.1",
    py_modules=['Game'],
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points = '''
        [console_scripts]
        Game=Game:cli
    ''',
)
```

game.py

```
from random import *
from time import *
import click

userinventroy = ["Phone"]

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
def bet():
    global dt
    global f
    guessthenumber = randint(1,2)
    dt = 5000
    f = open("wallet.txt","w")
    f.write(str(dt))
    f.close
    if int(input("Guess the number:")) == guessthenumber:
        print("Correct you won 250 DT!!")
        w = 250
        f = open("wallet.txt","r")
        old_wallet = f.read()
        new_wallet = int(old_wallet) + int(w)
        f = open("wallet.txt","w")
        f.write(str(new_wallet))
        f.close()
    else:
        print("You lost.")

@cli.command()
def wallet():
    global dt
    global f
    f= open("wallet.txt","r")
    print("You have :",f.read())
    f.close()
```

After you have these two files created I want you to go to the terminal and type
" pip install --editable . " (without strings).